# NS Reverse Lookup of AWS Endpoint IPs not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

Wasn't sure where to post this so I posted this here.

I'm using Squid in transparent mode to whitelist/blacklist outgoing traffic and output the results to the access.log.  Almost all SSL traffic is output as a destination IP address, however I want the host name for readability purposes.

I'm feeding all the access.log data to logstash and using the dns filter to do a reverse lookup for the destination IP.  This works with s3 if I have a vpc endpoint for S3, but doesn't work with any other service.

In debugging I can do a forward lookup on the host name, but cannot use that exact IP address in a reverse look up.  For example,

```
$ host kms.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
kms.us-west-1.amazonaws.com has address 176.32.112.55

$ host 176.32.112.55
Host 55.112.32.176.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

AWS would have to manage its own PTR records for its API endpoints, and for whatever reason, has chosen not to.  Most likely this is because `kms.<region>.amazonaws.com` is actually a round-robin or other high-availability record (when I looked up kms.us-west-1.amazonaws.com just now, for example, I got 176.32.118.139), and they do not want each IP that can be returned to map to the same domain record.

AWS does publish the CIDR blocks it uses.  (See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html for information and the JSON file link.)  You could try to map from that, although keep in mind it can be updated at any time.

Answer (score -1):

AWS takes control of managing reverse DNS, but that does not mean you cannot request the change.  To change your PTR settings, send a request to AWS using the following form:

https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true